# KE Attribute in MTL Files

Tags: 3d, .obj, wavefront

I have a .mtl file next to my .obj file which specifies the materials for the object. Im trying to create a parser but dont know what the "Ke" attribute means.
e.g:

```
Ka 0.78 0.78 0.78 
Kd 0.78 0.78 0.78
Ks 0 0 0
Ke 17 12 4 # What does this line mean?
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ke stands for emissive coeficient. It goes together with ambient, diffuse and specular and represents the amount of light emitted by the material. If you also have a defined emission color the material will irradiate light.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ka 0.78 0.78 0.78  # ambient color
Kd 0.78 0.78 0.78  # diffuse color
Ks 0 0 0           # specular color
Ke 17 12 4         # emissive coeficient. It goes together with ambient, 
                   # diffuse and specular and represents the amount of 
                   # light emitted by the material.
```